# Correlation in geometric brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $S_t$ the solution of
\begin{equation}
 \frac{dS_t}{S_t}=Y_tdt+\sigma dB_t
\end{equation}
where $B$ is a brownian motion and $Y$ is a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, with $d<Y_t,B_t>=dY_tdB_t=\rho dt$. Is it true that the solution remains
\begin{equation}
 S_t=S_0\exp\left(\int_0^tY_sds-\frac{1}{2}\sigma t+B_t\right)
\end{equation}
?

Comment: No, if $Y_t$ depended only on $t$, the answer would be yes, but it is not the case here. And even if there is no correlation, the answer is still no.

Comment: @NN2 . The answer is yes. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are typos in the exponential:
$$
S_t=S_0\exp\Big(\int_0^t Y_s\,ds-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{\color{red}2}t+\color{red}{\sigma }B_t\Big)\,.
$$
Writing $A_t=\exp(\int_0^t Y_s\,ds)$ we get a process of finite variation that has zero covariation with the Brownian motion. Then
$$
S_t=A_tM_t
$$
where $M_t$ is an exponential martingale that satisfies
$$
dM_t=\sigma M_t\,dB_t\,,\quad M_0=S_0\,.
$$
Noting that $dA_t=A_tY_t\,dt$ the integration by parts formula yields
$$
dS_t=M_t\,dA_t+A_t\,dM_t=M_tA_tY_t\,dt+\sigma A_tM_t\,dB_t=S_t\,Y_t\,dt+\sigma S_t\,dB_t\,,
$$
in other words, $S_t$ ***is*** the solution of
$$
\frac{dS_t}{S_t}=Y_t\,dt+\sigma B_t\,.
$$
When $S$ is a stock not paying dividends and $Y_t$ is the risk-less short rate this and similar models are very popular in financial mathematics.

Comment: Thank you very much for your anser, and I'm sorry for the typos. Yeah, I am studing some models of incomplete markets where I found this kind of equations.